# Suggestions for android layout

Tags: android

I currently got this complex screen to implement the XML code. 
[image]

I suppose to build with the tablelayout, but i still have no idea how to place the item on the shelf and the wooden background behind that. Could anyone hint me some ways ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the bitmap as your activity's background drawable. From there, you've got several possibilities. Two that should work are

1) Place transparent Button's on the activity, using an AbsoluteLayout.

2) A couple of people have coded solutions similar to the HTML image map construct, and posted them in public fora. Google "imagemap android" and borrow.